# When does exactly “execution of process” starts ? At what stage it is in cpu / memory?

Tags: operating-system

State of process is either defined by register content + program counter (when its on CPU ) or by memory layout i.e by text,data,heap and stack (when it’s in memory )

So when does we exactly say:

1. process has started its execution ?
2. It has various states through which it passes in its life-cycle , at what state it is in memory and at stage on CPU ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that the exact point where a process has started is either:

- When the scheduler first gives the process (or the process' initial thread or task) CPU time (for a relatively standard OS multi-tasking system where kernel isn't treated as a separate schedulable entity).
- When the kernel first returns from "kernel-space" to the new process' "user-space" (for a multi-tasking systems where kernel is a separate schedulable entity).
- At any (indeterminable) point during the creation of the process (for a system that doesn't support multi-tasking).

Answer (score 0):

The process context is defined by register values. Most processors have a Load Process Context instruction or the equivalent sequence of instructions that load a process's registers from its process context block. A process starts execution at the completion of this instruction (or sequence of instructions).

As far a process states go, those are entirely system specific.